# rescatar valor de un checkbox creado de forma dinamica en la pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una página que tiene una serie de controles `checkbox`, creados dinámicamente en una llamada `ajax` con la siguiente función:

```js
function fnObtieneRecetaPaciente(PacienteId) {
  var parametrosAjax = {
    "PacienteId": PacienteId
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(parametrosAjax),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetRecetaPaciente", "Carro")',
    success: function(RecetaPaciente) {

      if (RecetaPaciente.lstMedicamentos.length > 0) {
        var Medicamentos = "";
        $.each(RecetaPaciente.lstMedicamentos, function(idx, medicamento) {
          Medicamentos += "<div class='row' id='Medicamento_" + idx + "'>";
          Medicamentos += "<div class='col-lg-4'><div class='tcont'>" + medicamento.Medicamento + "</div></div>";
          Medicamentos += "<div class='col-lg-2'><div class='tcont'>" + medicamento.Prescripcion + "</div></div>";
          Medicamentos += "<div class='col-lg-2'><div class='tcont'>" + medicamento.Cantidad + "</div></div>";
          Medicamentos += "<div class='col-lg-3'><div class='tcont'>" + medicamento.Estado + "</div></div>";
          Medicamentos += "<div class='col-lg-1'><div class='tcont style='padding: 3.5px;'><input type='checkbox'";
          Medicamentos += "id = 'chkMedicamento_" + medicamento.MedicamentoId + "' class='chk' /></div ></div > ";
          Medicamentos += "</div>";
        });
        $('#divMedicamentos').append(Medicamentos);
      } else {
        var msgError = "paciente sin receta";
        $('#divMedicamentos').html(msgError);
      }
    },
    error: function(error) {
      var msgError = "Error al obtener los datos de la receta del paciente";
      $('#divMedicamentos').html(msgError);
    }
  });
}
```

Esto funciona sin problemas, los checkboxes son dibujados en la pagina según lo que me indique la base de datos.

Mi problema surge al momento de querer saber cuáles de estos checkboxes fueron seleccionados. En la misma pagina, tengo un `button` que me ejecuta una funcion, que recorre los elementos `checkbox` de la siguiente manera:

```js
$('.chk').each(function() {

});
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo puedo saber el valor del checkbox, para poder construir una estructura de los elementos que fueron seleccionados?

Answer (score 1):

Lo logre resolver de esta manera:

```
$('.chk').each(function () {                  
 if ($(this).prop('checked'))
 {
  alert('seleccionado --> ' + this.id)

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Para saber cuales fueron seleccionados debería acceder a la propiedad individual  `checked` en el `each` de cada elemento.

*Ejemplo javascript*

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('ver');
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
 var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.chk');
 elements.forEach(function(e){
   if(e.checked)/* Verificamos si está seleccionada*/
     console.log(e.value); /* Value del Check*/
   });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="2">2
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="3">3
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="4">4
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="5">5
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="6">6

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="ver">Ver</button>
```

*Ejemplo Jquery*

```js
$(function() {
  $('#ver').click(function(event) {
    $('.chk').each(function () {
       if($(this).prop('checked'))
         console.log(this.value);
     });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="2">2
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="3">3
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="4">4

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="ver">Ver</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

dentro del each, accedes al objeto con this

```
$('.chk').each(function(){
    var chk = $(this);
    if(chk.prop('checked')){
     alert(chk.val());
  }
});
```

el codigo muestra los valores de los checkbox que fueron seleccionados.

Answer (score 0):

Los eventos en elementos que se crean dinamicamente se manejan o capturan de manera distinta en java script con jquery

```
$("ul#pestanas_facturacion  ").on("click", "span",function (e) {
//ACA VA LO QUE QUIERES HACER
});
```

En el ejemplo anterior estoy capturando el evento click al elemento span que fue agregado dinamicamente a la lista Ul

MEJOR EXPLICADO introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]